# Azure WebJob hosting environment

Tags: azure, webjob

Is there any article or resources that list the type of .NET features and SDKs that work in a standard .NET console application, it does not work in Azure WebJobs hosting environment?

My understanding is that Azure WebJobs hosting environment is a typical windows server VM that includes .NET framework. I expect most of SDK based on .NET such as the variety of Azure SDK or Entity framework should work flawlessly in a WebJobs hosted console application. I like to know things that do not work in a WebJobs hosting environment before I make application design decisions.

Comment: I'm not aware of a list of things not working with WebJobs. I confirm Entity Framework is working with no problem. What kind of libraries are you planning to use that you think wouldn't work?

Comment: @VivienChevallier, I am looking for issues that might arise due to local security policy restriction or low privileged AD identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking for issues that might arise due to local security policy restriction or low privileged AD identity.

WebJobs run in a secure environment called a sandbox. The execution environment of sandbox is different from a local execution environment mainly due to multi-tenancy — because a single physical machine in the data center can be concurrently executing apps and services belonging to a large number of differing customers.

> I like to know things that do not work in a WebJobs hosting environment before I make application design decisions.

The sandbox generally aims to restrict access to shared components of Windows. Unfortunately, many core components of Windows have been designed as shared components: the registry, cryptography, and graphics subsystems, among others. This section outlines the limitations placed on usage of these often essential, yet shared components.

For more information, link below is for your reference.

[Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox)